# Array reduce and optional values in typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following foldable interface:

```
export interface Foldable<F> {
  reduce: <A>(fn: (b: A, a: A) => A, initial: A, foldable: F) => A;
}
```

And then I want to implement it for array:

```
export const getArrayFold = <A>(): Foldable<Array<A>> => {
  return {
    reduce: (fn, initial, array) => {
      return array.reduce(fn, initial);
    }
  };
};
```

But the compiler complains with:

> Argument of type '(b: A, a: A) => A' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type '(previousValue: A, currentValue: A, currentIndex: number, array:
>   A[]) => A'.   Types of parameters 'a' and 'currentValue' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'A'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.

I don't understand how there are two different types of `A` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two errors:

- You need to provide which type is array. You can't get it from single generic `Array<T>`, you need to introduce both `T` and `Array<T>`.
- Your type for function that is consumed by `reduce` is not adequate. Correct one: `(previousValue: A, currentValue: F) => A`

Explanation:

If you provide *initial* value with type (e.g. `string`) to reduce function, *previousValue* parameter is always same as *inital*.

See official [TypeScript reduce declaration](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b2bfccfce4dc725515907cb8842699965404cf00/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1092):

```
interface Array<T> {
    reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: ReadonlyArray<T>) => U, initialValue: U): U;
}
```

---

**Full code (refactored)**

```
interface Foldable<F, T> {
    reduce: <A>(
        fn: (previousValue: A, currentValue: T) => A,
        initial: A,
        foldable: F
    ) => A;
}

const getArrayFold = <T>(): Foldable<T[], T> => ({
    reduce(fn, initial, array) {
        return array.reduce(fn, initial);
    }
});

// Real implementation usage
const array: number[] = [1, 2, 3]
const initial: string = "";
const fn: (previousValue: string, currentValue: number) => string = (a, b) => a + b;

const newValue: string = getArrayFold().reduce(fn, initial, array);
```

See code on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Foldable%3CT%2C%20F%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reduce%3A%20%3CA%3E(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn%3A%20(previousValue%3A%20A%2C%20currentValue%3A%20F)%20%3D%3E%20A%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20initial%3A%20A%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foldable%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%3D%3E%20A%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20getArrayFold%20%3D%20%3CT%3E()%3A%20Foldable%3CT%5B%5D%2C%20T%3E%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reduce(fn%2C%20initial%2C%20array)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20array.reduce(fn%2C%20initial)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Real%20implementation%0D%0Aconst%20array%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0D%0Aconst%20initial%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20fn%3A%20(previousValue%3A%20string%2C%20currentValue%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20string%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20a%20%2B%20b%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20newValue%3A%20string%20%3D%20getArrayFold().reduce(fn%2C%20initial%2C%20array)%3B)

Comment: Thanks. My use case was different, but your answer reminded me that I needed to type my accumulator, which made everything good to go!

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to see what is going on if you change the generic type names:

```
export const getArrayFold = <R>(): Foldable<Array<R>> => {
```

Now you will get `Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'A'`. `array.reduce` uses different types for the current value and previous value, so you have type `A` (the generic type from your interface) and type `R` from your `getArrayFold` function.

You have not actually passed in the generic type `A` to `reduce`, so it considers it to be `A` from the interface which essentially just means it can't determine what the type is supposed to be.

One way I have found to do this is to allow your interface to specify the type of both `A` and `F`:

```
export interface Foldable<F, A> {
  reduce: (fn: (b: A, a: A) => A, initial: A, foldable: F) => A;
```

Now you can write your array function as

```
getArrayFold = <R>(): Foldable<Array<R>, R>
```

When you call it, you can do

```
getArrayFold<string>().reduce((a, b) => a + b, '', ['hello', 'world']);
```

This will give you type safety so you can't use `0` as a value or `.toFixed` on the `a`/`b` properties or things like that.